# Codeigniter Access model class outside root

Tags: codeigniter, class, model

I want load a model in root directory and access the model function in that file.

For example : I'm having test.php in root directory and having model class user.php in model folder.

In that user.php i have written the function named as fetch_all_user() it will return all the user of my database.

Now I want to access the fetch_all_user() function in test.php which is placed in root directory.

Please help

Comment: Can you explain why would you want to do this? Why not place the test.php under the `application/controllers` and the user.php under `application/models` as you would do normally?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why would you do that but here it is

```
require(APPPATH.'user.php');
```

Put above line in test.php and only if your user.php is in root of your app. But you have to know that's not the best practice for codeigniter or any MVC framework. I would do just as complex857 said.